# How do I check if a $_GET parameter exists but has no value?

Tags: php, get, isset, is-empty

I want to check if the `app` parameter exists in the URL, but has no value.

**Example:**

```
my_url.php?app
```

I tried `isset()` and `empty()`, but don’t work. I’ve seen it done before and I forgot how.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Empty is correct. You want to use both is set and empty together

```
if(!empty($_GET['app'])){
    echo "App = ".$_GET['app'];
} else {
    echo "App is empty";
}
```

Comment: Your "App is empty" will display if it's not set in the first place, I'd put an elseif statement in there

Comment: Indeed, a more accurate statement would be:

    if(isset($_GET['app']) && !empty($_GET['app'])){
        echo "App = ".$_GET['app'];
    } elseif(isset($_GET['app'])) {
        echo "App is empty";
    } else {
        echo "App is not set";
    }

Answer (score 5):

`empty` should be working (`if(empty($_GET[var]))...`) as it checks the following:

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Here are your alternatives:

`is_null` - Finds whether a variable is NULL

```
if(is_null($_GET[var])) ...
```

`defined` - Checks whether a given named constant exists

```
if(defined($_GET[var])) ...
```

Comment: If your parameter is an integer that can be zero, then empty fails if its value is zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( isset($_GET['app']) && $_GET['app'] == "")
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can simply check that by** `array_key_exists('param', $_GET);`.

Imagine this is your URL: `http://example.com/file.php?param`. It has the `param` query parameter, but it has not value. So its value would be `null` actually.

`array_key_exists('param', $_GET);` returns `true` if `param` exists; returns `false` if it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: `http://example.com/file.php?param` actually results in `isset($_GET['param'])` returning true!

Comment: This is an actual answer to the question. Thank you, Ali