# PHP making difference between get with and without value

Tags: php, get

Good day,

I would like to know if there is any function for making the difference between this:

```
?param=
```

and this:

```
?param
```

Because I would like my script to detect if value is empty (first example), or if it's not given (second example).

I made a test with the following functions but I could not find what I want:

```
if( isset( $_GET['param'] ) ) {
    echo '<div>isset</div>';
    
    if( empty( $_GET['param'] ) ) {
        echo '<div>empty</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div>not empty</div>';
    }
    
    if( is_null( $_GET['param'] ) ) {
        echo '<div>null</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div>not null</div>';
    }
    
    if( defined( $_GET['param'] ) ) {
        echo '<div>defined</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div>undefined</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<div>not set</div>';
}
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Solution:

```
( strpos( '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '?get=' ) !== false ) || ( strpos( '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '&get=' ) !== false )
```

Comment: You need to parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` yourself, you can't distinguish them in `$_GET`.

Comment: What I guessed, thank you @Barmar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503364/how-do-i-check-if-a-get-parameter-exists-but-has-no-value

Comment: The variable is only null if it's not set or retrieved directly from filter raw [see filter_input() for reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input). What you can check for is that it's set but empty. That's the only notable difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can test with something like if( $_GET['param'] ) which will give true if Param is declared (even if it is an empty string) and false if not declared.